# COMO DEVOLVER EL PRIMER ELEMENTO DE UN FOR EACH

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

BUENAS TARDES ESTOY REALIZANDO UNA SUBCONSULTA DE UNA TABLA EN ORACLE PARA TRAER LOS BENEFICIARIOS DE UN COTIZANTE POR MEDIO DE UN FOREACH NECESITO EN LA PARTE DE LA TABLA MOSTRAR SOLO UNA VES EL COTIZANTE, COMO SE PUEDE OBSERVAR EN LA IMAGEN

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

COMO PUEDO HACER QUE SOLAMENTE KARINA MENDEZ SE MUESTRE UNA VES?

Comment: Paul, bienvenido a SOes. Te pediremos dos cosas, 1. porfavor no escribas con mayusculas porque eso se entiende como que estuvieras gritando y no creo que sea el caso y 2. en vez de poner una captura de pantalla, considera usar las herramientas del sitio para incluir tu codigo de acuerdo al siguiente articulo: [mcve]. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

PODRÍAS USAR LA EXPRESIÓN **DISTINCT** EN LA CONSULTA , EN LA BD.

SELECT DISTINCT expressions FROM tables [WHERE conditions];

Comment: cito el comentario del buen @Kenny Barrera: "porfavor no escribas con mayusculas porque eso se entiende como que estuvieras gritando y no creo que sea el caso"

Answer (score 0):

Crea una variable `booleana` fuera del `foreach`, y dentro del `foreach` evalua su valor con un condicional, si el valor es verdadero agregas el `Beneficiario` y si es falso no. El valor por defecto de la variable debe ser `true` y después de la condición le asignas el valor `false`. De esa manera la condición del condicional solo se cumplirá en la primera iteración del ciclo.

```
$unaVez = true;

{foreach from=$respuesta key=key item=item}

    // ...
    if ($unaVez) {
        <tr> 
            <td><h1> Beneficiarios </h1></td> 
        </tr> 
    }

    $unaVez = false;
```